# What's the meaning of 'has been on it' in this joke?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the BGT show, a boy, Ned Woodman does a joke as performance. During his performance, he said

> Why are people so excited talking dog on Britain's Got Talent.
> Amanda Holden **has been on it** for years.

And they show audiences' happy face of laughing. But I don't know why it's so funny.

What's the meaning of 'has been on it' here?

---

This is the youtube link of the performance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qxIyOFkJeY

---

I listened to the joke in the wrong way and I fixed the content with the help of the comment below. ('spin on it' -> 'has been on it')

Comment: The boy says "Amanda Holden's been on it for years". The joke is that Ned is saying that there have other talking dogs before on that show, for example, Amanda Holden. He is implying that she does not have much talent. He pronounces "been" as 'bin' which is a London regional dialect variation.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks. It makes more sense now.

Comment: Amanda Holden is a type of lightweight celebrity who is chiefly famous for being famous.

Comment: Bernard Manning reincarnated!  Calling an ugly women 'a dog' is an outdated chauvenistic slur. This boy is alluding to this concept. His parents must be very proud.

Comment: "Has been on it" .........  Talking dogs on the telly is nothing new. Amanda Holden's been on it for years.( She is a dog and talks on TV).  QED.

Comment: @BruceMurray At first, I thought 'talking dog' means 'talking about a dog'. But then, Michael in the above comment implied a dog that can talk for the meaning of the phrase. A dog that can talk is not common but very special. Why is it nothing new? I'm getting confused again.

Comment: Do you get the part about comparing ugly women to dogs?  So, the boy is puzzled as to why people are suddenly excited about seeing a talking dog on the talent show when there has been a talking dog on the show for many years in the person of Amanda Holden (hah hah!). He is suggesting that she is a dog and talks. Hence, why is just another talking dog seen as an exciting novelty?

Comment: @BruceMurray Thanks!! I get it now. The boy is naughty indeed.

Comment: Good, because I was worried you might ask about the irony of why she is being called a dog when she is, in fact, very attractive.

Comment: @BruceMurray Honestly speaking, I understand the joke in a literal sense now but I don't feel quite funny. Is there any more story why British people feel so funny by describing the beautiful lady as a dog?

Comment: No malace was intended and, thankfully, there are still a few moderate thinkers who would refrain from taking to Twitter to demand he be 'burned at the stake', as they understand it was being said in jest by a child. The fact that he directed it at Amanda Holden would confirm that because clearly she is not 'a dog'.

Comment: @kevin012 - the joke is stupid and not funny. You need not worry if you do not find it funny.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Malace is a typo made in the comments but corrected in the answer.  But you already knew this, as does everyone else, so I can only wonder at what little pleasure you derive from its mention.  Get out more, find a hobby!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling an ugly women 'a dog' is an outdated chauvinistic slur. This boy is alluding to this concept. So, the boy is puzzled as to why people are suddenly excited about seeing a talking dog on the talent show when there **has been** a talking dog on the show for many years in the person of Amanda Holden (hah hah!). He is suggesting that she is a dog and talks. Hence, why is just another talking dog seen as an exciting novelty? I read this as an ironic gag with no malice intended and, thankfully, there are still a few moderate thinkers who would refrain from taking to Twitter to demand he be 'burned at the stake', as they understand it is being said in jest by a child. The fact that he directed it at Amanda Holden would confirm that because clearly she is not 'a dog'.

Comment: I don't believe that kid wrote that joke.

Comment: I agree, nor do I think Greta writes her own speeches. We should just let kids be themselves instead of our mouthpieces by proxy.

Comment: Greta Thunberg says “And yes, I write my own speeches. But since I know that what I say is going to reach many, many people I often ask for input. I also have a few scientists that I frequently ask for help on how to express certain complicated matters. I want everything to be absolutely correct so that I don’t spread incorrect facts, or things that can be misunderstood.”

Comment: I have no trouble in believing what Ms Thunberg says, nor with her viewpoint. She is a remarkable young woman, and an example to people three or four times her age. I say, just in case there is any doubt, BRAVO to her.